# Matrix Keypad Implementation problem: PICSimLab, PICGenios, PIC18F4580

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic18

I'm trying to use the matrix keypad in PICSimLab's PICGenios board with PIC18F4580 MCU. The schematic for the board is [here](https://lcgamboa.github.io/picsimlab_docs/stable/pdf/boards/PICGenios.pdf). Below is the code.

matrix_keypad.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_KEYPAD_H
#define MATRIX_KEYPAD_H

#define ROW1 PORTDbits.RD0
#define ROW2 PORTDbits.RD1
#define ROW3 PORTDbits.RD2
#define ROW4 PORTDbits.RD3

#define COL1 PORTBbits.RB0
#define COL2 PORTBbits.RB1
#define COL3 PORTBbits.RB2

#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY 400

void init_switch(void);
unsigned char scan_keypad(void);
unsigned char debounce_signal();

#endif
```

matrix_keypad.c

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "matrix_keypad.h"

void init_switch() {
    //digital pins.
    ADCON1 = 0xFF;
    
    //set first three bits as input & rest as output for PORTB.
    TRISB = 0x07;
    
    //set up PORTB internal pull-ups.
    RBPU = 0;

    //set PORTD as output.
    TRISD = 0;

    //set all row bits.
    ROW1 = ROW2 = ROW3 = ROW4 = 1;
}

unsigned char scan_keypad() {

    unsigned char ret_val = 0;

    //scan keys on row 1.
    ROW1 = 0;
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 1;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 2;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 3;
    ROW1 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 2.
    ROW2 = 0;
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 4;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 5;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 6;
    ROW2 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 3.
    ROW3 = 0;
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 7;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 8;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 9;
    ROW3 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 4.
    ROW4 = 0;
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 10;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 11;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 12;
    ROW4 = 1;

    /*if (ret_val)
        PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;              ----------->why tho?
    else
        PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;*/

    return ret_val;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <xc.h>
//#include "clcd.h"
#include "matrix_keypad.h"

void main(void) {

    init_switch();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i);

    while (1) {
        if (scan_keypad()) {
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 1;
        } else {
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I expect the `scan_keypad()` call in `main.c` to output a non-zero value as long as I press and hold any key in the matrix keypad. But what happens is not that - the RB7 LED runs with a duty cycle of about 50%, meaning my `scan_keypad()` call is outputting zero and a non-zero values in an alternating fashion.

I saw that this problem goes away and `scan_keypad()` behaves as expected when I add the following lines before returning from it:

```
if (ret_val)
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;              ----------->why tho?
        else
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;
```

The PORT bits can be any PORT bits. I've spent the whole day trying to figure out why and I'm not able to come up with an answer. Help me please.

Comment: Apparently you can use an oscilloscope. Please check the levels at the scanning port pins, output and input. You might want to use a multichannel scope, for example use one channel as synchronizing signal to be able to interpret the timing correctly. Do this with and without the part around RB6. -- How are the switches for LED1 and LED2 set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. But it is without any debounce treatment. Due to limitations of the PICSimLab simulator (I'm the developer), it is necessary to add a delay of at least 50 microseconds before reading the pins to work (normally the delay is added in the debounce treatment).

```
unsigned char scan_keypad() {

    unsigned char ret_val = 0;

    //scan keys on row 1.
    ROW1 = 0;
    __delay_us(50);
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 1;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 2;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 3;
    ROW1 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 2.
    ROW2 = 0;
    __delay_us(50);
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 4;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 5;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 6;
    ROW2 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 3.
    ROW3 = 0;
    __delay_us(50);
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 7;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 8;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 9;
    ROW3 = 1;

    //scan keys on row 4.
    ROW4 = 0;
    __delay_us(50);
    if (!COL1)
        ret_val = 10;
    if (!COL2)
        ret_val = 11;
    if (!COL3)
        ret_val = 12;
    ROW4 = 1;

    /*if (ret_val)
        PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;              ----------->why tho?
    else
        PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;*/

    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: Nice. It worked.

Regarding debouncing:
I actually have another function which is a signal debouncer. The switch press does not get debounced even when I put the above code through it.

Anyway, the 50ms delay works fine.